# AndroidStudio cannot resolve symbol for anything

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android project that I've been working on with no issues for a while. Now all of the sudden when I open it, every file is showing false errors. I get "cannot resolve symbol" for everything.

It still builds and runs correctly, but it's very annoying to have the red lines on every line of code. I've tried deleting the project and pulling it back down from GitHub, restarting AndroidStudio, and I even uninstalled/reinstalled AndroidStudio. Nothing works. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you have for actual errors, code, screen captures, anything at all.... Could be many issues, invalid build path, missing resources, etc.

Comment: Every line of code throws an error. "Cannot resolve symbol 'Dialog'", "Cannot resolve symbol 'Bundle'", "Cannot resolve symbol 'Build'", etc. The project still builds and runs though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I too had this problem. All I did was go to File, then invalidate cache/restart and it worked.

Comment: I want to kiss you on the mouth

Comment: That's how I felt when I found the solution to this too! It happened to me afterwards too and I had to keep doing it but it stopped after a while. Anyway, can you accept my answer and upvote it please cuz i just started here and need some rep.